# Programming a canvas in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to program a game in html and javascript, for this I decided to use a canvas, as it will make the development easier. However, when I try to implement another object into the canvas, the code seems to break, I have been fiddling with the code, in order to see the issue, however, I have had no success so far. The code can be found below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<Title>Game Prototype 1</Title>
</head>
<body onload= "startGame()">
    <canvas id="canvas" 
    style =  
    "border:1px solid #000000; 
     padding-left: 0;
     padding-right: 0;
     margin-top: 65px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     display: block;">
    </canvas>
<script>

var character;

function startGame(){
    gameArea.start();
    character = new character(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
}
var gameArea = {
    canvas:
    document.getElementById("canvas");
     start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 1000;
        this.canvas.height = 800;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas,document.body.childNodes[0]);
    }
function character(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y; 
    ctx = gameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.width, this.height, this.x, this.y);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output of the code is this:

[image]

At this point I am no longer sure whether the issue is which the character variable, and hence the character is not being displayed, or with the canvas, as the canvas has incorrect dimensions, I am not entirely sure why the canvas changes the dimensions (if the rectangle displayed on the screen is the canvas). This is what I mean by the code breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some syntax errors in the `gameArea` object. (A `}` was missing, and in Javascript you use `,` instead of `;` to separate members within an object.)

I recommend using the browser console to spot such issues. Here is your code with the object fixed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<Title>Game Prototype 1</Title>
</head>
<body onload= "startGame()">
    <canvas id="canvas" 
    style =  
    "border:1px solid #000000; 
     padding-left: 0;
     padding-right: 0;
     margin-top: 65px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     display: block;">
    </canvas>
<script>

var character;

function startGame(){
    gameArea.start();
    character = new character(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
}
var gameArea = {
    canvas: document.getElementById("canvas"),
    start: function() {
        this.canvas.width = 1000;
        this.canvas.height = 800;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas,document.body.childNodes[0]);
    }
}
function character(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y; 
    ctx = gameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.width, this.height, this.x, this.y);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Did this solve your problem or were you expecting something else to happen?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was expecting to happen, however, I always thought to separate members within an object commas are used, but thank you very much, I will keep the advice in mind about the console.

Comment: What I meant is that commas are indeed correct, but you had used semicolons. Glad to be of help :)